# javascript, simulate keyboard events, work on chrome(webkit)

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, keyboard-events

in FF, i've used this code:

```
if (keyCount == lineLimit) {
    // method in FF, no Chrome
    var mock = document.createEvent("KeyboardEvent"); // or KeysEvent
    mock.initKeyEvent("keypress",true,true,null,false,false,false,false,14,0);
    var x = document.getElementById('InputCategory');
    // rise height before Enter
    $(this).height(div_height + font_height + offset_height);
    // mock Enter
    x.dispatchEvent(mock);
    // init keyCount
    keyCount = 0;
}
```

it works, but could not be effective on webkit-based browsers like chrome.

so i asked google and found keyboard event is one of the DOM Level 3 events,here is an aticle: http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/

then i knew /* initKeyboardEvent */ is not supported on chrome & safari, /* initUIEvent */ i've tried, it didn't work also.

Do virtual keyboard events reall can be simulated on chrome ? plesase help me :)

Comment: Why don't you just insert a newline-char instead of trying to emulate enter-press?

Comment: @Alxandr that could work~ but now i just want to figure out how to initialize a keyboard event by js and work on chrome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works, but it's not generating a keypress-event, rather a text-insert event.

```
var te = document.createEvent('TextEvent');
te.initTextEvent('textInput', true, true, window, 'test');
<element>.dispatchEvent(te);
```

That inserts the word 'test' at the end of the input (in your case you'd probably replace that by `\n`.

Comment: Good~ this will work, but can you please teach me how to simulate a keyboard event in Chrome or just told me the possibility of it, many thanks~~

Comment: It is possible. I've seen it done, but haven't been able to do so myself. If you are satisfied with the answer though, please mark it as accepted.

Comment: Can you update this answer since it was [deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createEvent)?