# How you simulate keyboard events with Capybara in headless environment?

Tags: javascript, capybara, acceptance-testing, headless-browser

I'm trying to test complex web-app GUI, which involves some non-trivial keyboard interaction. I have unit tests for specific components of GUI, but I also use Cucumber and Capybara for end-to-end acceptance testing. I'm using headless Linux box for this, everything is done via ssh.

Problem is, **I can't find Capybara driver that supports Javascript, allows to simulate keyboard events and is headless**.

Summary of my research so far:

- [capybara-webkit](https://github.com/thoughtbot/capybara-webkit). Tried, studied lots of docs and code, found that it has no easy keyboard simulation, but I can write my own using [`execute_script`](http://rubydoc.info/github/jnicklas/capybara/master/Capybara/Session:execute_script) and this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4846687/javascript-simulate-keyboard-events-work-on-chromewebkit) or try to figure out how [`trigger`](http://rubydoc.info/github/jnicklas/capybara/master/Capybara/Node/Element:trigger) works.
- [Selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/). Has [`send_keys`](http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/rb/Selenium/WebDriver/Element.html#send_keys-instance_method), sounds perfect, but. "Provided Firefox is installed, everything is set up for you". I can't install Firefox but there is [Selenium-remote](https://github.com/Tho85/capybara-selenium-remote) which I can try setting up.
- [capybara-envjs](https://github.com/smparkes/capybara-envjs). Looks kinda hacky, has no documentation, but its possible to figure out how `trigger` works by looking at the code.

So, I'm tired of research and seeking for guidance.

Is there some obvious solution that I'm missing? What option from my list should it try first? Maybe someone has some useful experience with testing simulating Javascript keyboard events with Capybara in headless environment?

Comment: Why can't you install firefox?  If you're on a linux box without X windows, you can still install and run firefox headless: http://drumcoder.co.uk/blog/2010/nov/23/selenium-headless/